# Azure Bicep - load excel file in Bicep

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I would like to load the values from excel file, they are only names inside it and I have a lot of them. So I don't want to copy all of them and place them in an array. I want some solution if it's possible like [loadJsonContent].

Comment: No built-in feature to achieve this, you need to write code to achieve this, see my answer. :)

Comment: or use loadTextContent

Answer (score -1):

> I want some solution if it's possible like [loadJsonContent].

If you want built-in File function for bicep, **the answer is NO.**

From the official document, [File functions for Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-files) only have three:

[loadFileAsBase64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-files#loadfileasbase64)

Loads the file as a base64 string.

[loadJsonContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-files#loadjsoncontent)

Loads the specified JSON file as an Any object.

[loadTextContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-files#loadtextcontent)

Loads the content of the specified file as a string.

I think your requirement needs to achieve via writing code.

By the way, you didn't clearly define the excel file, xlsx or csv? And if possible, please provide a sample file format so that we can provide specific code.

For example, I have a Student.xlsx file like this(CSV file is also this structure.):

[image]

Then I can use this Python code to parse and get the data I want:

```py
import os
import openpyxl
import csv

#get the student name from 'Student Name' of sheet 'Tabelle1' of the file 'XLSX_Folder/Student.xlsx'
def get_student_name(file_path, sheet_name, col):
    student_name = []
    #if file_path ends with '.xlsx'
    if file_path.endswith('.xlsx'):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
        sheet = wb[sheet_name]
        #get all the values under the column 'Student Name'
        for i in range(col, sheet.max_row+1):
            student_name.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=col).value)
        print('This is xlsx file.')
        return student_name
    elif file_path.endswith('.csv'):
        #get all the values under the column 'Student Name', except the first row
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if reader.line_num == 1:
                    continue
                student_name.append(row[col-1])
        print('This is csv file.')
        return student_name
        print('This is csv file.')
    else:
        print('This is other format file.')

XLSX_file_path = 'XLSX_Folder/Student.xlsx'
CSV_file_path = 'CSV_Folder/Student.csv'
sheet_name = 'Tabelle1'
col = 2

print(get_student_name(XLSX_file_path, sheet_name, col))
print(get_student_name(CSV_file_path, sheet_name, col))
```

Result:

[image]

After that, parse your bicep file and put the above data into your bicep file.

The above code is just a demo, you can write your own code with the develop language you like. Anyway, no built-in feature of your requirement.